# Read remote file into Duplex NodeJS stream, then write the stream data into form-data upload

Tags: node.js, stream, multipartform-data, form-data

I am reading from a remote file on an SFTP server. The method to read the file takes a writeable stream, and writes the file data onto that stream before returning.

Once complete, I am passing this stream to form.append used by the form-data library, in order to upload that file data to an API.

The stream is declared like this:

```
const stream = new duplex({
    write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
      console.log('wrote chunk')
      callback();
    },
    read() {  
        console.log(`Read method called`)
      }
})
```

When the write method is called during the SFTP access, 'wrote chunks' is called multiple times. When the file upload using form-data is called, 'Read method called' is called once. After it is called, the HTTP request never completes.

Suspect my implementation of the read method on the Duplex stream is wrong, and the full file data is never read properly from the stream.

Is there a way I can validate what my problem is here or am I fundamentally misunderstanding how streams operate?

I have tried adding the following to the Duplex stream before it is passed to the form-data function, but none of it is ever called.

````
stream.on('data', () => {
        console.log(`Read bytes of data.`);
      });

    stream.on('end', () => {
        console.log('There will be no more data.');
    });

    stream.on('error', () => {
        console.log('error');
    });```
````